# Add IP clients to DRBL from command line

Tags: command-line, ip

Is there a way to add clients to a DRBL server from the command line ? (I would like the server to provide configurations for more IP addresses than configured in the initial configuration)

Comment: DRBL or DRBD? The tag (DRBD) and the question (DRBL) are completely different :)

Comment: Your are right, I made a mistake. I fix it, thank you !